# Show that a $C^2$-function $u$ is plurisubharmonic if and only if the Hessian matrix $H_u(z)(\omega, \omega)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables

I'm trying to show that the **theorem** in my book:

> A $C^2$-function $u$ is **plurisubharmonic** if and only if the matrix
>   (the complex **Hessian**) $$H_u(z)=\left( \dfrac{\partial^2
> u}{\partial z_j \partial \bar z_k} \right)$$ is positive semidefinite. It means that $\forall \omega=(\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n) \in \Bbb{C}^n$ then
>
> $$H_u(z)(\omega,\omega)=\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial z_j \partial \overline{z_k}}(z)\cdot \omega_j \overline{\omega_k}\ge 0$$

**Solution**

$\bigstar $ We'll prove that $\forall z \in \Omega, \omega \in \Bbb C^n,\xi \in \Bbb C $ then $$\dfrac{1}{4}\Delta_\xi u(z+\xi\omega)\mid_{\xi=0}=\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial z_j \partial \overline{z_k}}(z)\cdot \omega_j \overline{\omega_k}$$

- Since $\xi=x+iy \in  \Bbb C \implies \left\{\begin{matrix}
   & x=\dfrac{\xi+\overline{\xi}}{2}\\ 
   & y=\dfrac{\xi-\overline{\xi}}{2i}
  \end{matrix}\right.$
- Since $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{\xi}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \ \text{and} \ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial {\xi}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\dfrac{i}{2}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ we have
  $$ \begin{align*}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial  \xi \partial \overline{\xi}} &=\dfrac{1}{4}\left (\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}  \right )\\ &=\dfrac{1}{4}\Delta _\xi u \tag{I}\end{align*}$$
- Now, I have stuck when I want to show that 
  $$\dfrac{\partial^2 u (z+\xi\omega)}{\partial  \xi \partial \overline{\xi}}\mid_{\xi=0}=\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial z_j \partial \overline{z_k}}(z)\cdot \omega_j \overline{\omega_k} \tag{II}$$

$\bigstar $ Since $(I)$ & $(II)$ we're done.

But How can we show that $(II)$?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(II) is a computation with the multivariable chain rule. Applied once, the  rule yields 
$$\dfrac{\partial u (z+\xi\omega)}{\partial  \xi }=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial  u}{\partial z_j }(z)\cdot \omega_j \tag1$$
Now, if the right side is denoted $g(z)$, we have the analog of (1), 
$$\dfrac{\partial g (z+\xi\omega)}{\partial  \overline\xi }=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial  g}{\partial \overline z_k }(z)\cdot \overline \omega_k \tag2$$
Plug the formula for $g$ into the right side of (2), and conclude.

Comment: Wow! It's great! Now, I see and I'll rewrite your hint. Thanks! **user98975**

Answer (score 0):

Show that $(II)$:

- We have: $$\forall z \in \Omega \subset \Bbb C^n, \omega \in \Bbb C^n, \xi \in \Bbb C \implies z+\xi \omega =\left (z_1+\xi \omega_1,\ldots, z_n+\xi \omega_n  \right ) \in \Bbb C^n$$
- Applying the multivariable chain rule, we have: $$\dfrac{\partial u (z+\xi\omega)}{\partial  \xi }\mid_{\xi=0}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial  u}{\partial z_j }(z)\cdot \omega_j:=g(z) $$
- Thus, **LHS** of $(I)$ becomes:$$\begin{align*}\\ \dfrac{\partial g (z+\xi\omega)}{\partial  \overline\xi }\mid_{\xi=0}&=\dfrac{\partial^2 u (z+\xi\omega)}{ \partial \overline{\xi} \partial  \xi}\mid_{\xi=0}\\ &=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial \overline{\xi} }\left ( \sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial  u}{\partial z_j }(z+\xi \omega)\cdot \omega_j \right )\mid_{\xi=0}\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial^2  u}{\partial z_j \partial \overline z_k }(z)\cdot \omega_j \overline{\omega_k} \blacksquare \end{align*}  $$
  We're done!