# Can we construct a compact complete pluripolar set?

Tags: analysis, several-complex-variables, potential-theory

We know that analytic sets are not relatively compact in $\mathbb{C}^n$ when $n\geq 2$. In fact, we can construct plurisubharmonic functions by holomorphic functions. So analytic subset belong to pluripolar set. In term of this, can we construct a compact compelete pluripolar set?
Of course, trivial example like discrete points should be excluded.

Comment: This https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229519/examples-of-pluripolar-sets might be interesting.

Comment: According to wikipedia if $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^2$ then $f$ is plurisubharmonic iff $(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_i \partial \overline{z}_j})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ is positive semi-definite. Thus, we could take $f(z_1, z_2)=\vert z_1\vert^2+\vert z_2\vert^2-1$ and get that we can realize the sphere as the zero locus of a plurisubharmonic function.

Comment: I  construct the function $f(z_1,z_2)=\log(|z|^2-1)\quad(|z|^2 > 1); f(z_1,z_2)=-\log(1-|z|^2)\quad (|z|^2 \leq 1)$ by your hint. I think that the function is psh and its pluripolar set is compact in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Your function is quite different from the one I suggested. Also the zero locus of your function is just the origin.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515707/show-that-a-c2-function-u-is-plurisubharmonic-if-and-only-if-the-hessian-ma for an explanation why the fact wikipedia claims holds true. Also note that for my function we can write $f(z_1, z_2)=z_1\overline{z_1}+z_2\overline{z_2}-1$ we easily compute $(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_i \partial \overline{z_j}})_{1\leq i,j\leq 2}= Id_{2\times 2}$ which is positive definite.

Comment: I know this conclusion. I realized that the function I constructed is incorrect, for $\log(|z|^2-1)$is not plurisubharmonic function when $|z|^2 \geq 1$. In fact, I want to construct a plurisubharmonic function with compact poles. The zeros locus of your function is compact, how can we construct the poles of a plurisubharmonic function through the zero locus of plurisubharmonic function?

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered the definition. I do not really know how to construct a suitable function (respectively, whether it is possible at all).